# Why is my $opword not equal to $query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Hello i want to change my password which is coming from my database, the very first thing i want to verify the users old password, but my $query is not equal to `$opword`, what might be the reason ?

I am trying to get the result from past 8 hours but I dont know where I went wrong please do help me thanks in advance.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('../includes/config.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
require_once('../includes/config.php');
$opword = $_POST['opword'];
$npword = $_POST['npword'];
$cpword = $_POST['cpword'];
$string = "SELECT password FROM admin WHERE username = '$_SESSION[uname]'";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,$string);
if($opword == $query) {
    echo "yup";
}

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <?php

require_once('includes/menu.php');

?>

   <form action="changepassword.php" method="post">

       <p><label>Old Password:</label><input type="password" name="opword"></p>
       <p><label>New Password:</label><input type="password" name="npword"></p>
       <p><label>Confirm Changed Password:</label><input type="password" name="cpword"></p>
       <input type="submit" value="Change Password" name="submit">

   </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Apart from that being open to an sql injection attack..... have you actually tested that `$query` has a return value? Have you debugged this code?

Comment: Read more about mysqli_query and what kind of object it returns

Answer (score 1):

Because you are try to compare password with result object. You need to fetch password field form your data result

```
if($opword == $query->password) {// fatch password form result data
```

> Note:- Don't store plain password into database

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use prepared statements and hash your passwords before store them in database ([password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)).

```
$session_username = $_SESSION['uname'];
//Take only one username
if ($stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT password FROM admin WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $session_username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    if ($row['password'] == $opword) {
        echo 'yup';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the following statement:

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,$string);
```

Use this before comparing compare:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
if($opword == $row[0]) {
   echo "yup";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using xdebug or var_dump(), you would find that $query is a PDOStatement, and object which will never equal a word.

You need a function get the data. Here is the [documentation](http://php.chinaunix.net/manual/zh/mysqli.query.php) for mysqli queries.

Answer (score 0):

Basically

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbc,$string);
```

mysqli_query returns a resource not value. So you have to fetch values from it

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc or mysqli_fetch_array
```

any of above function can be used. Both function returns array. Then you can use array value to match with other value. Hope it will help you.